# how to remove html tags in ImperaviRedactorWidget in yii framework

Tags: php, yii1.x, yii-widgets

How to remove html tags in `ImperaviRedactorWidget` in `yii` framework so as to prevent script alert tags from displaying when the widget is used in `yii`?

(striptags don't work for this widget)

Answer (score 0):

striptags work fine.

which widget are you using?

A lot of them and each has its own problems, that are not related to imperavi

I use it:
https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget

Comment: I'm using ImperaviRedactorWidget in yii 1.. i'm not able to stip off tags coming in the content of the widget..

Comment: i finally found out that strip tags does work on the widget but does not work if you give tags explicitly in the editor( for eg: if you give <h1> test </h1> ,It treats <h1> as &lt; character). Thanks Maksym Tymofeiev